# Remove last characters of strings using regex

Tags: php, regex

I need to find a way in PHP to remove the last portions of 2 strings using regex's. This way once they are stripped of the extra characters I can find a match between them. Here is an example of the type of string data I am dealing with:

```
categories_widget-__i__
categories_widget-10
```

So I would like to remove:

```
-__i__ from the first string
-10 from the second string
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you identify the last portion of your strings ? With '-' ? You don't really need regex for that

Comment: All answers below work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(.*)-
```

This simple regex can do your job if - is the splitting criteria

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rX0dM7/7

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below code to remove all the characters from `-` upto the last.

```
<?php
$text = <<<EOD
categories_widget-__i__
categories_widget-10
EOD;
echo preg_replace("~-.*$~m","",$text);
?>
```

Output:

```
categories_widget
categories_widget
```

`-` matches the literal `-` symbol. And `.*` matches any character following the `-` symbol upto the end of the line. `$` denotes the end of a line. By replacing all the matched characters  with an empty string would give you the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str1 = "categories_widget-__i__";
$str2 = "categories_widget-10";
$arr1 = explode("-", $str1);
$arr2 = explode("-", $str2);
echo $arr1[0];
echo $arr2[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the last occurrence of a hyphen the only thing that's important?  If so you don't need regex:

```php
$firstPart = substr($str, 0, strrpos($str, '-'));
```

[**» example**](http://ideone.com/1wgWCF)